# How does a transaction verified with Truffle test?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test

I'm a new to Ethereum and Solidity, and I don't understand how Truffle executes *transaction calls*.

From what I learned and understood, if I try to use a contract method which changes the contract's state(changes any values), this means I(sender) have to make a transaction to that contract. In this way, I need my account's data, such as private key, or this stuffs are done by Metamask.

But I don't see any signing or verification process in the test code provided by [Truffle docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript#examples). In `it` block, just execute any contract's method, and we can see the changes.

Does this mean Truffle internally addresses the verification stuff, as this is test environment provided by itself? I don't get how Truffle test handle transactions. Can somebody explain what is going on inside the box? Or maybe I'm missing some of the concepts.

Thank you for advance for your explanations.

Comment: are you using Ganache to test?

Comment: @MajdTL That's right. All default settings.

Comment: the accounts in Ganache are not locked, so the request can sign the transaction with the public key

Comment: @MajdTL Oh that is interesting. So there is no need to provide the private key to sign...

Comment: no sorry i worte public key instead of private key...., anyway there is an option in Ganache where you can lock all accounts

Comment: Oh anyway, thank you for your explanation. @MajdTL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truffle test by default uses ganache which is a local blockchain running inside your computer.

When you start Ganache CLI, it will automatically create 10 accounts associated with 10 private keys. Each account has 100 ethers for testing purpose.

When you send a transaction that modifies blockchain data or you just transfer ether, truffle test already has access to the private keys provided so it doesn't need you to make an extra step.

Hope I was clear!

Comment: So does this mean even if I write test scripts for contracts and they all passes, when it comes to using it in the real situation, there has to be explicit processes related to signing and verifications - either by using `Metamask` or something else?

Comment: @cadenzah Exactly! Though truffle test is mainly used to test the contract within a local blockchain

Comment: Thx for your explanation

Comment: hi there! Do you know what's the best way to also sign messages with web3 from within a truffle test? `web3.eth.accounts.sign` requires a privateKey